# Xcode 9 Swift 4 Terminated due to memory issue (returning a cell)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Now I know there are lots of other questions out there with the same problem, however, none of them are crashing at the point mine is.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellView.frame.height / 2

    cell.animalLbl.text = elements[indexPath.row]
    cell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: elements[indexPath.row])
    cell.animalImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.animalImage.frame.height / 2

    return cell
}
```

> return cell

That is the line that's causing my problems. My array is only 10 items long and it is working fine on the simulator. It was also working fine on my iPad before I added all the images in on the table view.

Here is my array as asked:

```
let elements = ["The Perfect Apps", "Soft Boiled", "Medium Boiled", "Hard Boiled", "Scrambled","Fried", "Poached", "Rate", "Credits","Website"]
```

[image]

Comment: can you show elements array ?

Comment: I have added the array @Sh_Khan

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem, in the end, was that my image files were too big and so took too much memory to load. All I had to do was reduce the quality of them.

Comment: I'm trying to debug this error in a watchApp. In your case, how did you determine where the error occurred? Was it just dumb luck, or was there something you identified which might help me locate the problem?

Comment: It was really quite lucky as I was just re - making some graphics whilst I waited for a response and realised my images were massive files for tiny pictures on screen. Once I downsized these it worked fine! How you succeed.

Comment: What pisses me off is that Apple builds code with messages like this, but doesn't have the professionalism to provide the supporting documentation. I mean, just how damned uninformative is "...memory issue..."???

Comment: I completely aggressively

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not passing in the indexPath into your cell. You may want to use this instead:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

Also, you might not be registering the cell. This one always trips me up and causes an unexplained crash (make sure it's in your `viewDidLoad`):

```
tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

**EDIT:** 
After realising you're using a nib, you may want to try this as your register cell. You may want to go into your storyboard and double check that your nib is named CustomTableViewCell. If not, change it to whatever it is called:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

Comment: I have nothing named CustomCell, what should this be? (I have the identifier but not the actual thing.)

Comment: @MattPidd Apologies. I've renamed it to the correct cell you've used  (CustomTableViewCell). I've edited the code above.

Comment: I've got another error. Attached photo in the main question. Cheers for the help

Comment: @MattPidd You'll want everything inside your viewDidLoad underneath the super.viewDidLoad() btw. Can you confirm that the CustomTableViewCell is an actual class? i.e class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { }

Comment: Yes, it is a class in another view controller, confirmed. Does that make a difference? added another image for help in main question

Comment: @MattPidd After your screenshot, it looks like you're loading a nib file. I've edited my answer above again. Hope this helps!

Comment: Using your newest code I'm still getting the error about not being able in to invoke register with an argument list of type(the image in main question)

Comment: @DanielDramond I think everything should would however I don't know how to find the name of my nib